# How to Grab Selected str.replace Value From Regex in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Ok, I understand how the title might be a bit confusing, let me elaborate.
So to start I am making a BBCode input section. Then it will transfer the code from BBCode to HTML. Now the problem is I am having MINIMAL issues. Let me post my code before I continue:

```
var newer = $('#my_textarea').val().replace(/\[b\]/gi, '<b>');
```

Now let me say this, it replaces the `[b]` tags correctly with the `<b>` tags. My problem is I do not know how to do that for all tags. I have tried shortening the code by using this:

```
var newer = $('#my_textarea').val().replace(/\[(?:b|u|i)\]/gi, '<???>');
```

Then it will replace all tags (bold, underline, and italicize) with the correct HTML tags. Yet how would I go about doings this? How would I replace the HTML tag with the the BBCode tag found? What I mean is with this part of the regex `(?:b|u|i)` where it selects any of the three letters, how could I add that same letter to the HTML tag? Do you understand what my problem is? :) Please Help, Thank You!!

Comment: One way is make array for all the bb tags , loop over array to create a regex and replace  for each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$2` to get the second selected group

```
var newer = $('#my_textarea').val().replace(/(\[(b|u|i)\])/gi, '<$2>');
```

A good site for understanding and creating RegEx: https://regex101.com/

To catch also `[b],[u],[i]` and also `[\b],[\u],[\i]` use the following:

```
var newer = $('#my_textarea').val().replace(/(\[((\/?)(b|u|i))\])/gi, '<$2>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) One question though, why $2 and not $1?

Comment: If you enter `/(\[(b|u|i)\])/gi` into the site i gave you you'll see that the first group $1 is the expression we're replacing and the second one is the letter within the brackets.

Comment: Any idea on how to write that into one expression? Otherwise it would be a whole extra line :( Also thank you, the first part works PERFECTLY!

Comment: Oh so sorry! xD I forgot to add my question lol. Do you know how I could add the [tag] and [/tag] all in one expression? So there is a closing tag as well.

Comment: Updated my answer for that too :)

Comment: You are literally the best! :) It work 100% perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The regex below will convert the BBCode to HTML:

```
result = subject.replace(/\[(b|i|p)\](.*?)\[\/(b|i|p)\]/g, "<$1>$2</$3>");
```

You'll need to add more tags but you get the idea.

---

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/sp5597aj/1/